て + 得だ: What does it mean?
様々な色の笑顔を咲かせられる人は、自身をあやせて得だと思う
The character in his internal narration thinks this. What exactly am I to make of "得だ" here?
As far I can gather he's saying that a person who can make bloom all kind of smiling faces (Who can make many people smiles, can also humor/comfort himself.
What to make of 得だ? I assume it's not verbal form but とく? He has the advantage of being able to soothe himself?

Please provide more context. The usage of the verb あやす looks abrupt to me, and it's hard to imagine what's going on.

The lines before are
"三回忌ともなれば、離島といえど３０人の参列はくだらないだろう。今のところ滞りは感じないが、こなせているかというとそうではない。"
"忙しない姿はまるで虐められているかのようであり、同情心をいだかせた。そして、少しの罪悪感を負わされた……"
The character is commenting that despite being  a big 三回忌 they placed only one servant to serve everyone.  Thus the servant is permanently overworked and it's having a bad time.
Then his friends says this:
「っお風呂楽しみですねー」
Which prompt the main character to think that.


得 means "advantage", and 得だ means "is an advantage" or "is advantageous".
The verb あやす is almost exclusively used with a crying/fussy baby. Some dictionaries explicitly include "baby/infant" in its definition. You seem to be seeing an exceptional usage where あやす is deliberately used referring to an adult. In such cases, it typically carries a sarcastic nuance implying that the person is being treated like a whining infant.

The literal translation is:

様々な色の笑顔を咲かせられる人は、自身をあやせて得だ。
A person who can bloom smiles of various colors can soothe themselves (like a baby), and it is an advantage.

Considering the reason why the verb あやす is used, the sentence may have a sarcastic nuance like "How convenient to be a person who knows how to find small happiness and comfort themselves even in a situation like this". He is probably thinking that ordinary people won't look forward to a bath in this situation.
